# mysterious issue using Vue with Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, vue.js

Using Laravel Homestead with Vagrant, I've just spawned a new laravel project. During a fresh `npm install` to make use of `vue` and all other default front-end libraries Laravel ships with, I got the following warning:

> npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace
>   it, following the guidelines at
>   https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5

Initially i thought nothing of this warning, but after quickly setting up the default scaffolded `Vue` example environment Laravel ships with and running the app in the browser, i get the following console error:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <ExampleComponent>
       <Root>
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="en" lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
        <example-component></example-component>
    </div>
  </body>
   <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</html>
```

**APP.JS**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

**PACKAGE.JSON**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    }
}
```

**Laravel-Mix JS**

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

What seems to be the issue?

Comment: Post your package.json as well.

Comment: check update... its default that ships with laravel @devk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I went on and installed a fresh copy as well. And I got the same error (except I didn't get gulp deprecation notice, so that must be something you have installed globally probably).

As per [this answer](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1882) I then added `.default` after require statement in app.js and it started working:

```
...
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
...
```

And since `require(..)` is pre-ES6 I recommend doing it with ES6 syntax instead:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';

window.Vue = Vue;

Vue.component('example-component', ExampleComponent);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Comment: yes adding `.default` was the fix... what was the purpose for this new suffix?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not completely sure how `require(..)` (pre-ES6) statements work. When exporting you can export multiple variables, but you can also set one as default (so you don't need to do `import {Component} from './somewhere`, you can just do `import Component from './somewhere'`). Seems to me that `require(..)` statement has a problem recognizing the default export and you have to explicitly define that you're importing the default export.